# Ubuntu conected at VGA port adds a red tint to HDMI ports

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, colors, vga

I connected one of my computers with an Intel onboard video card to my LCD TV via VGA port, since it is the only video output that the computer has. After installing Ubuntu when I got back to the HDMI source of the TV, the colors were distorted. In particular, the image now has a red tint. After colors re-calibration on the TV service menu, I installed Windows 7 and everything was fine, ie, the problem was gone.

I really would like to stick to Ubuntu. Of course, there is always the option of buying a VGA to HDMI converter. But that would not respond to this so intriguing question...

Comment: Can you look for `*.icm` files under Windows and report back if you found any?

Comment: Yes. Actually I found 110 files. Txs!

Comment: 110?  I was hoping for 1 or 2 or 3...  Could you do a `start` type `cmd` - Right-click on the top icon and "run as administrator".  then type `cd \ ` and then `dir *.icm /a /s` and post the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link back?  Some background info: I'm trying to colour calibrate your monitor under Ubuntu with the `.icm` files from Windows.

Comment: Done! Let me just tell you one thing: the TV's VGA port - the one where the computer is connected - stays Ok all the time. It's the HDMI ports that get the red tint after I use it with Linux.

Comment: Erm, posting it is fine, but you need to provide the link it generates back to me...  Otherwise I'm never going to find it amongst all the other uploads... :P ;-)

Comment: Of course! ;) http://paste.ubuntu.com/10164211/

Answer (score 0):

Please:

- copy `C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm` to a USB stick,
- rename it to `.icc`
- boot Ubuntu
- go to system settings in the top right corner of your screen
- go to device colour profiles (the rainbow flower)
- If you have a device that looks like a screen, open it
- click "add profile"
- take "other profile"
- navigate to the USB stick
- click on `sRGB Color Space Profile.icm`
- click "Import"

### Obrigado!

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: After testing... Sadly it didn't work! "Obrigado", anyway. That was a awesome effort. I learned from it, no matter the outcome...